# imageNamed leads to bad fluency in iOS9

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios9, imagenamed

Development Environment：iOS9 Xcode7

In tableView，if cell set image with [imageNamed:],  it will make bad fps and bad lag phase.

So Why ?

Just apple changed its underlying mechanism or just iOS9 with bad optimizer ？

And now, there are so many tableViews, so many cells, so many images in my app, it's really a serious problem, so can u help me ?

Comment: Table views work like a clock if configured properly. You need to post `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` if you need help for your problem.

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear, I mean [imageNamed:]  this method works with low efficiency in iOS9.

Comment: This isn't a question, it's a rant. Did you measure it? Did you look at your images? Maybe you got images from clueless designers? Maybe you are doing something else completely wrong?

Comment: Got similar issues and seems lika a lot of other people are experiencing the same problem: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17888